# SlickEdit's "Indentation guide" equivalent for VS2010?

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2010, indentation

SlickEdit "Editor Gadget" is a free plug-in for the Visual Studio 2008 editor, with many tools that enhance a coder's productivity and have used it extensively.

However, I use Visual Studio 2010 now and cannot find the same plug-in for that version. More specifically, I am now searching for an alternative to the "Indentation guide". It consists in a vertical line drawn under the cursor from bottom to top of the current document, very useful to find the end of a long `if{ ... }` block !
Is there any alternative for VS2010 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Indent Guides](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30), an open source plugin for Visual Studio 2010 that just adds vertical lines at each indent level.

Edit : for VS2013, [the Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) from Microsoft do the job perfectly !

Comment: Yep, I found that plugin a few weeks ago and I'm using it since then. I forgot I had posted a SuperUser question about that, here's a point for you !